Question on error term (Introduction to Statistical Learning)
In an Introduction to Statistical Learning the authors state:

More generally, suppose that we observe a quantitative response $Y$ and $p$ different predictors, $X1, X2, . . . , Xp$. We assume that there is some dependent relationship between $Y$ and $X = (X1, X2, . . . , Xp)$, which can be written in the very general form $Y= f (X) + ϵ$. Here $f$ is some fixed but unknown function of $X1, . . . , Xp$, and $ϵ$ is a random error term, which is independent of $X$ and has mean zero. In this formula- error term, $f$ represents the systematic information that $X$ provides about $Y$.

I’m having a hard time understanding what $ϵ$ is representing. I thought this might be the error we got in estimating the function using statistical learning methods like linear regression, but I think I am wrong. The author goes on to talk about reducible and irreducible error. Reducible error can be minimized because this error comes from our estimate of $f$. So by getting a better estimate the reducible error decreases. But I don’t understand what irreducible error is. The author says it’s the variability associated with $ϵ$, but what does this mean.
Finally the author states:

Consider a given estimate $\hat{f}$ and a set of predictors $X$, which yields the prediction $\hat{Y}=\hat{f}(X)$. Assume for a moment that both $\hat{f}$ and $X$ are fixed, so that the only variability comes from $ϵ$. Then, it is easy to show that
$E(Y−Y)^2 = E[f(X) + ϵ -\hat{f}(X)]^2 = [f(X)−\hat{f}(X)]^2 + Var(ϵ)$

The author indicates that $[f(X)-\hat{f}(X)]^2$ is the reducible error and $Var(ϵ)$ is the irreducible error. Again, I’m having a hard time understanding what the irreducible error is.
Can someone explain what $ϵ$ is in the first equation, what irreducible error means, and how reducible and irreducible error relate to the first equation? The equation I’m referring to when I say the “first equation” is $Y= f (X) + ϵ$. Thank you in advance!

The $\epsilon$ is just a noise term. The predictors don't entirely explain $Y$ and the degree to which they don't is quantified by $\epsilon$. For example, suppose $Y$ is the price of a house and $X_1$ is square footage. Of course, house price is not just some deterministic function of square footage. The $\epsilon$ quantifies the error from all the other factors we aren't considering.

That makes sense. Is this what they’re meaning by irreducible error also?

I think you can interpret this like, we could reduce the portion of error coming from $[f(X)-\hat f(X)]^2$, by choosing a better $\hat f$, (choose a better function of $X$ as a predictor), but we could not reduce the portion of error coming from $Var(\epsilon)$, because it's noise indepenent of $X$ so we call it irriducible.

Ok that makes sense. So am I understanding everything correctly? We have $Y$ and we want to find a function that can predict $Y$ given our input $X$. So our goal is to achieve $Y = f(X)$ but we are going to have error because we can’t get an $f$ that can perform perfect. So now we have $Y=f(X) + ϵ$

Yeah its like assumption: $Y=f(X)+\epsilon$. We model it like $\hat Y=\hat f(X)$. How bad did we do? Well let's calculate the squared error: $\mathbb{E}[(Y-\hat Y)^2] = \mathbb{E}[(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat f(X))^2]= \mathbb{E}[(f(X)-\hat f(X))^2] + \text{var}(\epsilon)$ where the last step we used that the variance of independent random variables is the sum of the variances. So by improving $\hat f$ we can make the LHS go to zero, but we are stuck with the inherent noise from the $\epsilon$ which we can't reduce so its irreducible.

What are the random variables here? Is this related to $ϵ$ being random, having a mean of 0 and being independent of X?

They're all random variables except for $f$ which is deterministic. $\epsilon$ is random because its the noise term and $X$ is random because its from your input data which we sample from like drawing a chip from a jar and then apply the deterministic map $f$ to obtain our prediction.

Ohhh ok that makes sense. So would f(X) be random since X is also random? Is that why you said “the variance of independent random variables is the sum of the variances”?

Exactly! Just some function of a random variable. In the same flavor as squaring a Gaussian: $X\sim \mathscr{N}(0,1)$, and looking at $X^2$.

Thank you for your response and taking the time to answer my questions! I appreciate it!

No problem! Good luck with your studying!
